# How to get CloudFoundry MySQL connection parameters?

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

I have deployed a Spring application on CloudFoundry with MySQL service.
I want to connect to that CloudFoundry MySQL instance from MySQL Workbench/QueryBrowser.

Is there a way to get connection params(driver, url, username, password) for that mysql db on CloudFoundry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to connect with cadlecott application ([vmc tunnel](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html)) to your mysql service. You can use the provided username, password and service name to your MySQL Workbench.

e.g.

```
vmc create-service mysql mysql-test
vmc tunnel mysql-test
Service connection info: 
  username : u5B3ShwOIX40c
  password : p2VoxZqZQRxTz
  name     : d5dc313431cff4046b68798a8bba1328c

Starting tunnel to mysql-test on port 10000.

**1: none**

2: mysql

3: mysqldump

Which client would you like to start?: 1
```

(    Select the 1st choise)

Then open the MySQL Query Browser and use the above username/password.
Set the hostname to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and remember to set the port number. The default is 10000.

Comment: Currently I am using STS to deploy my app on CloudFoundry. I will try to install VMC and try it. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

please take a quick read though the documentation for vmc tunnelling here :- http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html

As Nikos already pointed out, just select option one after connecting the tunnel and then use the supplied parameters to connect MySQL Workbench.